# Angular components declared in shared module not recognised in feature modules after importing shared module in feature's module

Tags: angular

I have imported the shared module into my appModule and used one of its components without issues but doesn't work when I imported my shared module into in my feature module.

Shared Module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    CarouselModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    CarouselComponent,
    SpinnerComponent,
    OverviewComponent,
    TableComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    CarouselComponent,
    SpinnerComponent,
    OverviewComponent,
    TableComponent
  ],

})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Feature Module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    IncidentsContainerComponent,
    NewIncidentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IncidentsRoutes, // feature routing
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    TimepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NgSelectModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [
    IncidentsService
  ]
})
export class IncidentsModule { }
```

In my feature module component am just using the TableComponent selector:

```
<app-table></app-table>
```

and I get this error:

> 1. If 'app-table' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message.

The TableComponent :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() elements: Array<any>;
  @Input() headers: Array<string>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('...from table ', this.headers);
    console.log('...from table ', this.elements);
  }

}
```

This is my project structure:

[image]

Comment: What you've shown looks correct. Are you sure that "app-table" is the correct selector for the TableComponent ?

Comment: Please show the relevant code, in this case the Table component

Comment: @Kurt Hamilton I have updated the post to add the Table Component's code. Yes 'app-table' is the correct selector.

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu Which component are you using `<app-table>` in?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I'm using it in the incidents-list.component.html, which is declared in the IncidentsModule. And I have also imported the Sharedmodule into the same module, so I thought should be able to access the shared components exported in my SharedModule but the error makes no sense to me. See my project structure screenshot in the post.

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu That component isn't declared in your module? Can you make sure your post contains all relevant code.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Ohhhhh, how could I miss that!!!! I always thought I had the component declared in its module. Thanks for pointing that out. I feel so stupid now that I missed that. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

In case any one in the future having the same issue, even though the error I was getting was referring to the shared component *('app-table')* exported in my SharedModule but the issue was that I forgot to declare the Component in which I am referencing the shared component *('app-table')* in its own Module. I think the error Angular should have given is that the component in which I am using my shared component is not registered in any Module and it would have been more clearer and straight forward.